# In App Purchase problem for non consumable products

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing an application in which user can purchase any image he likes. For this i have implemented the in app purchase functionality as consumable products. That means if user purchase the same image again, he has to pay for that again. But apple rejected this application by saying that the product should be non-consumable in this case.

Now the problem is i have to create unique product id for every image and the number of images are around 1800. So, do i need to make the 1800 ids in the itunesconnect?

Also, there is a parameter in itunesconnect that:

```
   For Review
```

When you have tested your in app purchase and are ready to approve it and submit it for review, upload a screenshot below. This is for review purposes only and will not be displayed in the Store.

For this do  i need to add screen shot by testing each and every image?

Please provide any simple solution for the problem.

Thank s in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 1800 unique products, you will need 1800 entries in the store.

There isn't an automated means for uploading product information so you will have to do it all by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am creating ids now for every product. I need to know one more thing that for approval to the ids i need to add the screen shot which actually has a pop from the sand box environment that you purchase is successful. Just need to know whether i have to check every product id on device and save that image and then upload it on every id on itunesconnect or i just upload one image for every id that i saved by checking any one id.

Comment: I don't know for certain, I would suppose that you only need to upload one image per product.  That said, it would be a good idea to test your images on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you *maybe* also come away with a generic image IAP object, that's consumable. But you have to provide additional server infrastructure to make sure a account can be created and purchases can be restored.

And even then, it seems to be a thin line. There are however apps in the store that work this way.

Update (Feb 2012): It's not working anymore. Apple rejected the latest app using this technique. I'm sorry.